# How to set cookie with values from url before js is loaded

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I have a Laravel project and I am using react with it, I have a requirement where I need to deep link a page with country code, the link contains the country code which later gets sent from the client side in a header to get more information from the API. 
The problem is when I get the country code and set cookie by parsing the URL in my main blade template where all my scripts and style-sheets are included, my react component makes the API call before the cookie is set.
I tried setting the cookie in the controller but that makes no difference.

How do I handle this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you try to add your js code in `onload` event ?

Comment: It's actually something laravel is handling as it bundles the js once the project is compiled

Comment: in your react component did you call you `API` in `componentWillMount` ?

Comment: Yes, and actually I cannot change that to another hook

Answer (score 2):

you can set script in the head tag as it's first child, like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var query = location.search
      var country = getCountry(query) // Implement this method yourself
      setCookie(country) // Implement this method yourself
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

The script will be executed before loading other resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should share your code in order to get better help, but a way is using callbacks, 
You should set your cookie and write a callback for it to call api, (callbacks run when your main action finished completely)
. you can read more in these links

[About callbacks in react](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/callback-functions-in-react-e822ebede766)

[Async calls may help you as well](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/await-react/)

Hope these help you